# How do I specify your social profiles to Google?

Tags: google, json-ld, knowledge-graph

A while back I began noticing that big organisations (for example, Nike) have social icons in the search results (knowledge graph). After a little digging, I found a guide on how to [specify your social profiles to Google](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/customize/social-profiles). They mention that your profile must be a verified profile to appear in the results - my Facebook page is.

I've used the exact JSON-LD code to link to all of my social profiles and it's been around a month now but I can't see my Facebook page in the search engine results.

I tried the [troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/customize/social-profiles#troubleshooting) section but that doesn't work. There is no area in which you can click "wrong" near your company name.

Has anybody else managed to report social profiles that aren't appearing in the results?

Comment: So your business gets the Knowledge Graph panel (showing your business name, description, possibly some stats etc.), but it doesn’t contain the social links? Or is it that it doesn’t even display the panel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify, when you say, I tried the troubleshooting section but that doesn't work. There is no area in which you can click "wrong" near your company name, are you referring to troubleshooting for a Knowledge Graph displayed for a  local business? If yes, Google doesn't typically display social profiles in this Knowledge Graph. If you click the feedback button you're taking to Google maps. Google displays social profiles in the other Knowledge Graph. To better explain, see knowledge graph for Starbucks Coffee in screenshot below - if you click feedback the click the error box pops up then you can click on any of the sections to provide feedback. If you perform a search for a Starbucks location, for example, Starbucks 1101 Market Street San Francisco (sorry can't add a second link) and click feedback you're led to Google maps.

If you perform the search for the location you'll also see that Google displays different info in the KG, which is extracted from the Google listing. Google typically extracts info for the other knowledge graph from sources like Wikipedia. This Knowledge Graph is typically displayed for well-known entities, for example, large brands, celebrities etc. Also note, Google only displays profile links if they feel they're helpful to the search user.

[image: Starbucks Brand]

Comment: So in short, Google only caters for the big players!

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say big players but well-known entities, I've seen Knowledge Graphs displayed for smaller companies. Is the information typically displayed in this Knowledge Graph available for your company anywhere online? Having a Wikipedia page is helpful for this reason. Marking up the same info at the official website can be helpful too.

Comment: The only time I've ever seen knowledge graph working is when there's a Wikipedia page for the business. I don't know if I've ever seen it work without!

Comment: @GraceMassaLanglois My client  has a Wikipedia page and without providing any markup the KG was showing Company Info + Wikipedia info. Then I applied Social Markup on the homepage and I could see that markup in Google Webmaster Tools. However my social profiles are not visible on the Knowledge Graph. So should I provide this markup site wide or it should only be on the homepage ?

Answer (score 1):

The same situation is faced by me it's a 3 months now & the social profiles is still not shown in **Knowledge Graph**. I had research a lot upon it & reached upon the conclusion that if there is a Wikipedia page related the website then social icon appeared otherwise not.

Is it there your previous organisations having Wikipedia Page?

Comment: Our business does not have a Wikipedia page. I guess we will wait and see if they eventually appear!

Comment: I am talking about your previous organisation where social profiles appeared. Is it there Wikipedia page?

Comment: I don't have a previous organisation, I just meant other companies such as "Nike" etc.

Comment: As per my experience it never comes without Wikipedia page.

Comment: My client is an e-commerce marketplace. They have Wikipedia page and I provided Social Profile Knowledge Graph on every page. I could see the structured data markup on 80,000+ pages when I login to Webmaster Tools. However, on the Google SERP, the social profiles are not visible. What should I do so that it becomes visible?

Comment: Now a days even Wikipedia page not needed if you had taken care all your social profiles & their Structured Snippet insert upon your website correctly. (OG, Twitter Card etc)

Comment: I did. I have for FB, YouTube, Twitter, Google+, Instagram, LinkedIn. Right now I could see the structured data markup for more than 85,000 pages under Google Webmaster Tools. There aren’t any warning messages received from Google. However, it’s not appearing !! The site has more than 40,000 sessions in a day!! I don’t know what and how should I reply to my client.